# Get address of offset formula in another cell Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am working with a group of very complicated offset formulas. I need to see which cells they reference (excel visually highlights the cell off of which the offset is based). The offsets are to a large degree, so I can't manually use my mouse or arrow keys to navigate to them. I can use the `cell()` function to find the answer - by manually pasting the full `offset()` formula into the second argument of the `cell()` function. However this is onerous, and I am working with hundreds of such offset formulas, and I dont have time to manually paste all of them.

Manually, if I type `cell("address", OFFSET(D50, 5, 5))` it works fine.

I can get the offset formula alone using `formulatext(A1)`. However, the following fails: 
`cell("address", formulatext(A1))`.
Even if I use an additional cell to store the result of `formulatext()`, that still doesn't work.

Is this possible for the `cell()` function?

Comment: You can if you extract the three values that must be passed to the `OFFSET` function ( `D50`, `5` and `5`) and then use `INDIRECT`-- it's going to be a long, messy formula and I have to wonder why you'd want to do that to yourself.

Comment: sorry, whats the more elegant solution to which you refer?

Comment: I don't make a reference to a more elegant solution...

Comment: oh sorry. so you just meant that pasting the offset formula manually is easier. but this would be impossible for thousands of rows

Comment: You may want to explain what exactly you are trying to do as I think we are approaching [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory

Comment: I tried to clarify my use case. Please let me know if it remains unclear or if you have additional questions. Thanks

Comment: rather than seeking help for the solution you are trying to implement, perhaps share a concise subset of the workbook along with a sample of the desired result. Use images, sample input data that can be copied and a description of the transformation from the provided text sample input to the mocked up desired result image.

Answer (score 0):

Idea : generate offset() function parameter using cell B2,B3&B4, then generate the row & column number, re-find it using A1 as reference.

1st let type in "D50"(text) into B2, 5 into B3, then 5 into B4. let B1 have `=ROW(OFFSET(INDIRECT(B2,TRUE),B3, B4))` and C1 have `=COLUMN(OFFSET(INDIRECT(B2,TRUE),B3, B4))`

then in the cell formula.. change it to `=CELL("address",OFFSET($A$1,$B$1-1,$C$1-1))` .

p/s : This will need you to type in the D50, 5, 5 only once.. note that the cell() formula is the same throughout the sheet.